# Internal server issue in PayPal Sandbox developer account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When I am going to connect my website with PayPal Sandbox account I get an error:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@paypal.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log."

Why this error? It was working before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some sandbox downtime over the last 24 hours. The internal teams were able to find the issue and fix the immediate problem. Sandbox should now be up and running (if not, please let me know). The team is also looking into the root of the problem to ensure this doesn't happen in the future.